# R graphs, cannot paste the original R graph in a word document

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have not been able to copy and then paste, or just insert an R generated graph in an MS world document. Once pasted in a word document, the graph loses its original format and design. The captions and titles change font size and the legends are dislocated. 
Is there a way to import the R graph into a Word document without losing the original features which are visible in the R plotting window. I usually save my graphs as 'Metafile' because it is the only format that preserves quality of the graph but not the text i.e. annotations, legends and titles on the graph.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible that this question really belongs on [Super User SE](http://superuser.com/)? I think it may qualify under their [on topic criteria](computer software), as this does not concern programming directly but is about software and file formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hit "export" on the plots tab, save as an image (say .png), tick the "Maintain aspect ratio" box, and then up the width or height to get a very detailed plot saved as image. However, text size relative to the image will change, the same as if you zoom in to the plot and change the zoom window size. So you may want to identify what level of detail you want in your saved image (you can see how it changes in preview), and then adjust font size and legends accordingly. This way you can save an image exactly as you want it, and be sure that it will not change when you insert it into Word.